# Proving that a closed set and a topologically closed set are equivalent in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I know that  a subset $A \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is a closed set, when for every sequence ($x_k$)$_{\in \mathbb{R^n}}$ $\subset A$  with $x_k$ -> $ x\in \mathbb{R^n} $

(for $k$ -> $\infty$) follows, that $x \in A$.

Furthermore, a subset $A \in \mathbb{R^n}$ is a topologically closed set, when $A^C$ is open.

How can I prove that the former characterization and the latter are equivalent out of closed sets in $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: It depends on how you define *open set* in $\mathbb R^n$. How about this: A set $U$ is open if, for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb R^n$ converging to a point $x\in U$, we have $x_n\in U$ for some $n$. Is that your definition of open set? Or is it something about $\varepsilon$-balls?

Comment: It is the former definition, that we have $x_n \in U$ for some $n$

Comment: In that case there's nothing to it, just follow the definitions. Now, if open sets were defined in terms of $\varepsilon$-balls, then you'd have something nontrivial to prove.

Comment: You can use that for every $\epsilon>0$ you find a large $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$ you have $x_n\in B_{\epsilon}(x)$ where $x$ is your limit.

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from / inspired by some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A^c $ is open.

That means if for every {$y_n $} $\to x$ with $y\in A^c $, then some of the $y_i $ are in $A^c $.

Suppose {$x_n$} is a sequence where all the $x_i\in A $ and $x_n $ converges to some $x $.

If $x\in A^c$, then some of the $x_i $ are in $A^c $.  But that is not the case.  So $x $ can not be in $A^c $.  So $x\in A $.  So A is closed.

Now suppose $A $ is closed.  Suppose $\{y_n\} $ is a sequence the converges to a $y\in A^c $.

If all $y_i\in A $ then,  because $A $ is closed, that would mean $y\in A $.  But that is not the case.

So some of the $y_i $ are not in $A $.  So some of the $y_i $ are in $A^c $.  So $A^c$ is open.